# What is meant by $\frac{d ^2y}{dx^2}$?

Tags: derivatives, notation

I have this homework question:

Find $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ for $y = (x^3−5)(2x+3)$.

But I do not know why there are squares in $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$, so I cannot solve it. What is meant by this?

Comment: They want you to find $y''$ and they decided to use an inferior notation to make it a challenge.

Comment: @GitGud How is that an inferior notation?

Comment: Differentiate $y$, then differentiate the result.

Comment: @crash It creates a completely unnecessary dependence on a variable, it's more troublesome to write, takes up more space, it's more troublesome to type in $\LaTeX$, wastes more ink, pencil, ...

Comment: @GitGud Sure, but those are mostly typesetting criticisms. I don't think it's objectively inferior, but it is kind of a pain. That I'll certainly admit.

Comment: @MarkFischler You changed the question with your edit--unless the OP meant what you changed it to.

Comment: @GitGud, do you have a better notation for the "second-derivative operator" $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$?

Comment: @SantiagoCanez Yes: $''$ with suffix notation. And how often do people really need to treat differentiation as a functional anyway?

Comment: Surely your book has discussed this notation for second derivative before this point.  If not, complain about it!

Comment: @GEdgar I think this is a cultural thing. In my country up to (and including) high school, the prime notation is the only notation. I'm not commenting on whether this is good or bad, just that it happens in a whole country. Maybe it's not the only one.

Comment: @GitGud You must have also used the notation $y^{(n)}$? Otherwise, how else would you write the $n$th derivative? Surely you did not write
$$
\Large y^{\underbrace{\prime\cdots\prime}_{\text{$n$ times}}}
$$
did you?

Comment: @GitGud You see derivatives *before* high school in your country?  Why?  If your high schools correspond to the same ages as those of American high schools, I can't help but think you must be shortchanging basic algebra and geometry.

Comment: @crash I don't think I did before university. Where I come from there's no need to introduce the notation for higher order derivatives, we don't get into stuff like Taylor's polynomial and whatnot.

Comment: @GitGud I'll stop commenting so as to reduce noise, but my comment was more to elicit a laugh from you--who could ever use such awful notation? I was just inserting a joke for some comic relief. :)

Comment: @Bye_World I didn't say we did, but it's possible we do see derivatives in the 9th grade (not sure about this) in an axiomatic way. And we don't do Synthetic Geometry - this I think is a flaw, not because of the geometry itself, but because of the proof-based nature of the subject.

Comment: @GitGud: You, too.  If your book has only primes up to some point, and then has the problem stated with $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$, then complain about it!  I'm guessing that RayKay's book mentioned that notation before assigning such a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The operator $\frac{\mathrm d^2}{\mathrm dx^2}$ is the square of the operator $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}$ and as the latter is "take the derivative", the former means "take the derivative twice in  a row" or "take the second derivative".

Comment: Yes. It's a slight abuse of notation, because it should really be $\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^2$. It is abuse of notation because there is no meaning for $\frac{d^ny}{dx^m}$ for $n\neq m$. Or at least none that I've ever seen, although $n=m+1$ would be a differential form, I suppose.

Comment: Thank you, I will accept this answer in 3 mins when it will let me. My answer is 24x^2+18x. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. You can always [check Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=second+derivative+%28x%5E3-5%29%282x%2B3%29).

Answer (score 2):

The notation $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ simply means the *second derivative* of $y$ with respect to $x$. There are all sorts of [notations for differentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation). It would be smart to familiarize yourself with them.

For your problem specifically, you have
$$
y=(3x-5)(2x+3) = 6x^2-x-15.
$$
Thus, you have 
$$
y' = 12x-1
$$
and then
$$
y'' = 12
$$
for your answer, where the "prime" notation is here used to indicate how many derivatives you are taking.

Comment: It is $x^3-5$, not $3x-5$.

Comment: @user31415 Another user changed it as it is now. It was really OP's fault. Check the edit history.

Comment: OP at first said x3-5. I have never seen anyone denote $3x$ by $x3$, and I wouldn't have assumed he meant 3x. But I know of no rule that says $x3\neq 3x$, so I can't argue with you.

Answer (score 1):

It is abuse of notation meaning
$$
\frac{d\frac{dy}{dx}}{dx}
$$where pretending that $d$ and $dx$ are really symbols, you get the "fraction" $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$. So it means "differentiate $y$ with respect to $x$, then differentiate the result with respect to $x$", or for short "calculate $y''(x)$".